# How do I get my form to use new information after errors are corrected?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm search but i'm not 100% how you get this to resubmit, using new information, I've got all the errors up and showing as appropriate, but in terms of, how to hit the submit button again, and then it reassesses the form; how do i go about this? Any help would be appreciated.

html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>RATool</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cfcss.css">
   <script src="cf.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1> Health Authority </h1>
    <h2> Contact Form </h2>
      <form>
       <fieldset>
         <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
            <input name="fname" id="fname" class="formfield" type="text">
            <span id="errfname" class="error">*This is required</span>
            <span id="errfname1" class="error">*Name fields must have more than one character, and do not contain numbers
                    or other non-allowed alphabetic characters. The only character the last name
                    field should legitimately contain is a hyphen (e.g. Whittaker-Jones).</span>
            <span id="errfname2" class="error">*This can only contain alphabetic numbers and if desired, one hyphen</span>
         <br>
         <label for="sname">Surname:</label>
            <input name="sname" id="sname" class="formfield" type="text">
            <span id="errsname" class="error">*This is required</span>
            <span id="errsname1" class="error">*Name fields must have more than one character, and do not contain numbers
                or other non-allowed alphabetic characters. The only character the last name
                field should legitimately contain is a hyphen (e.g. Whittaker-Jones).</span>
            <span id="errsname2" class="error">*This can only contain alphabetic numbers and if desired, one hyphen</span>
         <br>
         <label for="title">Title: </label>
              <select name="title" id="title">
                <option value="Please select">Please select</option>
                <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
                <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
                <option value="Miss.">Miss.</option>
                <option value="Master.">Master.</option>
              </select>
             <span id="errtitle" class="error">*This is required</span>
         <br>
         <br>
         <br>
         <label for="HANo">Health Authority Number:</label>
         <input name="HANo" id="HANo" class="formfield"type="text">
            <span id="errHANo" class="error">*This is required</span>
            <span id="errHANo2" class="error">*This must be in format ZHA123456 (ZHA followed by 6 numbers)</span>
         <br>
         <br>
         <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input name="email" id="email" class="formfield"type="text">
            <span id="erremail" class="error">*This is required</span>
            <span id="erremail2" class="error">*Please enter a valid email</span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="telno">Telephone Number:</label>
                 <input name="telno" id="telno" class="formfield" type="text">
                <span id="errtelno" class="error">* If a telephone number is entered, then it should contain only numbers, not
                letters, or other disallowed characters. A valid Zedland telephone number has
                11 digits (no spaces)</span> 
                <span id="errtelno1" class="error">*This must just be numbers</span>
            <br>
            <button onclick="checkForm()">Submit</button>
        </fieldset>
       </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
   function checkForm(){    

    var errors=document.getElementsByClassName('error');
    for(var i=0;i<errors.length;i++){
        errors[i].style.display='none';
    }   

    if (document.getElementById("fname").value == "" ) {
        document.getElementById("errfname").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("errfname").style.visibility = "visible";
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (document.getElementById("fname").value.length < 2 ) {
        document.getElementById("errfname1").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("errfname1").style.visibility = "visible";
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (document.getElementById("fname").value.length > 1) {
        checkFName();
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (document.getElementById("sname").value == "" ) {
        document.getElementById("errsname").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("errsname").style.visibility = "visible";
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (document.getElementById("sname").value.length < 2 ) {
        document.getElementById("errsname1").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("errsname1").style.visibility = "visible";
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (document.getElementById("sname").value.length > 1) {
        checkSName();
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (document.getElementById("title").value == "Please select" ) {
        document.getElementById("errtitle").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("errtitle").style.visibility = "visible";
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (document.getElementById("HANo").value == "" ) {
        document.getElementById("errHANo").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("errHANo").style.visibility = "visible";
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (document.getElementById("HANo").value.length > 0) {
        if (checkHANo());
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (document.getElementById("email").value == "" ) {
        document.getElementById("erremail").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("erremail").style.visibility = "visible";
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (document.getElementById("email").value.length > 0 ) { 
        if(checkEmail());
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (document.getElementById("telno").value.length != 11 ) { 
        document.getElementById("errtelno").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("errtelno").style.visibility = "visible";
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (document.getElementById("telno").value == /^\d+$/ ) {
        document.getElementById("errtelno1").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("errtelno1").style.visibility = "visible";
        e.preventDefault();

    }
 }  

 function checkEmail(){
 var email = document.getElementById('email');
 var emailRegEx = /[-\w.]+@([A-z0-9][-A-z0-9]+\.)+[A-z]{2,4}/;

 if (!emailRegEx.test(email.value)) {
       document.getElementById("erremail2").style.display="inline";
       document.getElementById("erremail2").style.visibility = "visible";
       return true;
 }
 e.preventDefault();
 }

 function checkHANo(){
    var HANo = document.getElementById("HANo");
    var hanoRegEx = /[ZHA]\d{6}/;

    if (!hanoRegEx.test(HANo.value)) {
        document.getElementById("errHANo2").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("errHANo2").style.visibility = "visible";
        return true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}

function checkFName(){
var first = document.getElementById("fname");
var firstRegEx = /^[a-zA-Z-]{2,40}$/;

if (!firstRegEx.test(first.value)){
    document.getElementById("errfname2").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("errfname2").style.visibility = "visible";
    return true;
}
e.preventDefault();
}

function checkSName(){
 var sec = document.getElementById("sname");
 var secRegEx = /^[a-zA-Z-]{2,40}$/;

 if (!secRegEx.test(sec.value)){
    document.getElementById("errsname2").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("errsname2").style.visibility = "visible";
    return true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: What's your issue?

Comment: If an error is corrected, i need to be able to hit submit again, and it realises the error is corrected, and error message goes. At the moment, once the error is there, is doesn't go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error messages are displaying by default. To hide those add the CSS class below:

```
.error{ display:none; }
```

Add this piece of code at the beginning of `checkForm()` to re-hide the message when error is corrected. Eg:

```
var errors=document.getElementsByClassName('error');
for(var i=0;i<errors.length;i++){
    errors[i].style.display='none';
}
```

Instead of calling the `formCheck()` function on `onclick` of the button, call it `onsubmit` of the form with a `return`. Like

```
<form method="post" action="yourpage" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
```

To show all errors, declare a variable with default value as `true` like `var isValid=true;` just above/below the `for loop`
Eg:

```
function checkForm(){    
var isValid = true;
var errors=document.getElementsByClassName('error');
for(var i=0;i<errors.length;i++){
    errors[i].style.display='none';
}   

if (document.getElementById("fname").value == "" ) {
    document.getElementById("errfname").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("errfname").style.visibility = "visible";
    isValid = false;
}

if (document.getElementById("fname").value.length < 2 ) {
    document.getElementById("errfname1").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("errfname1").style.visibility = "visible";
    isValid = false;
}

if (document.getElementById("fname").value.length > 1) {
    isValid = checkFName();
}

if (document.getElementById("sname").value == "" ) {
    document.getElementById("errsname").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("errsname").style.visibility = "visible";
    isValid = false;
}

if (document.getElementById("sname").value.length < 2 ) {
    document.getElementById("errsname1").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("errsname1").style.visibility = "visible";
    isValid = false;
}

if (document.getElementById("sname").value.length > 1) {
    isValid = checkSName();
}

if (document.getElementById("title").value == "Please select" ) {
    document.getElementById("errtitle").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("errtitle").style.visibility = "visible";
    isValid = false;
}

if (document.getElementById("HANo").value == "" ) {
    document.getElementById("errHANo").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("errHANo").style.visibility = "visible";
    isValid = false;
}

if (document.getElementById("HANo").value.length > 0) {
    isValid = checkHANo();
}

if (document.getElementById("email").value == "" ) {
    document.getElementById("erremail").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("erremail").style.visibility = "visible";
    isValid = false;
}

if (document.getElementById("email").value.length > 0 ) { 
    if(checkEmail());
    isValid = false;
}

if (document.getElementById("telno").value.length != 11 ) { 
    document.getElementById("errtelno").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("errtelno").style.visibility = "visible";
    isValid = false;
}

if (document.getElementById("telno").value == /^\d+$/ ) {
    document.getElementById("errtelno1").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("errtelno1").style.visibility = "visible";
    isValid = false;

}
return isValid;
}
```

NOTE: You have to return `false` from other functions such as `checkEmail()`,`checkHANo()` also if there is error. It seems you are returning only `true`. And remove all `e.preventDefault()`

That's it

Comment: Ok and this needs to go after each if statement i'm guessing?

Comment: Will this re assess the form on hitting submit, and remove error messages if they have been corrected?

Comment: I've put it after all the if statements, and it still seems to not get rid of the error, even if i correct it

Comment: I see you do not have any `form`. Wrap all the element inside a form including button

Comment: can you use jQuery?

Comment: can't use jquery for this bit no

Comment: I've put the form in but now when  i hit submit it flashes rather than staying up - how do i get around this? thanks

Comment: so the form is submitting I guess. That's where `e.preventDefault()` comes to stop submitting if there is any error.

Comment: I've amended the js on here, but only the first error is now showing? Is meant to be after every if?

Comment: Brilliant that's so helpful thank you. I understand what you mean. Where would I insert the alert for when it is submitted?  Would it be in for loop at the top - if isValid = true, alert(... ; or would at be at the end because it has got to pass through all the functions first?

Comment: just above the `return isValid`. But you cannot alert after the form is submitted for that you've to submit through AJAX which is jQuery

Comment: Oh ok no worries, that's fine. Thank you very much!